# How to generate an XSLT for OAI-PMH response?

Tags: xml, xslt, oai-pmh

I have some xml data,which I need to index into solr core. For this I need to generate XSLT file for mapping my custom XML data to solr required format XML (1).
Here my custom data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <responseDate>2021-06-24T06:02:01Z</responseDate>
  <request verb="ListRecords" metadataPrefix="oai_dc" set="p15869coll19" from="2020-09-01" until="2020-09-30">http://digital.americanancestors.org/oai/oai.php</request>
  <ListRecords>
    <record>
        <header>
            <identifier>oai:digital.americanancestors.org:p15869coll19/17</identifier>
            <datestamp>2020-09-21</datestamp>
            <setSpec>p15869coll19</setSpec>
        </header>
        <metadata>
            <oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
                <dc:title>Papers of Abraham C. Ratshesky</dc:title>
                <dc:identifier>P-586</dc:identifier>               
                <dc:relation>01</dc:relation>
                <dc:subject>Halifax Explosion, Halifax, N.S. 1917; Massachusetts, General Court. Senate; American Red Cross. Boston Metropolitan Chapter</dc:subject>
                <dc:description>Photographs; Morse Family</dc:description>
                <dc:rights>Open access</dc:rights>
                <dc:rights>User has an obligation to determine copyright or other use restrictions prior to publication or distribution. Please contact the archives at jhcreference@nehgs.org or 617-226-1245 for more information.</dc:rights>
                <dc:language>English</dc:language>
                <dc:source>Wyner Family Jewish Heritage Center, New England Historic Genealogical Society</dc:source>
                <dc:identifier>http://digital.americanancestors.org/cdm/ref/collection/p15869coll19/id/17</dc:identifier>
            </oai_dc:dc>
        </metadata>
    </record>
  </ListRecords>
 </OAI-PMH>
```

**Is it available to generate XSL file for the above XML response?**
I have tried to generate with an online XML-XSLT generator but no success.
Here what I tried: I am using this online [generator](http://xsltransform.net/).
My input XMl is above.

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="">

<xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <add>
        <xsl:for-each select="OAI-PMH/ListRecords/record">
            <doc>
                <field name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="header/identifier"/>
                </field>
                <field name="ss_title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="metadata/oai_dc/title"/>
                </field>
                <field name="ss_relation">
                    <xsl:value-of select="metadata/oai_dc/dc:relation"/>
                </field>
                <field name="ss_description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="metadata/oai_dc:dc/dc:description"/>
                </field>
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </add>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Desired output:

```
 <add>
      
  <doc>
      <field name="id">oai:digital.americanancestors.org:p15869coll19/17 </field>
      <field name="ss_title">Papers of Abraham C. Ratshesky</field>
      <field name="ss_relation"> 01</field>
      <field name="ss_description">Photographs; Morse Family</field>
   </doc>
       
 </add>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The XSLT in question should be manually crafted.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried to generate it with an online generator, but it doesn't print the right template.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML uses some namespaces, which your stylesheet does not take into account.

Instead of:

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="">
```

try:

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
    xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="oai_dc dc">
```

You also need to replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="metadata/oai_dc/title"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="metadata/oai_dc:dc/dc:title"/>
```

and make a similar correction to the value of `ss_relation`.